# Windows 8 push notification without associating the application to windows store

Tags: azure, windows-8, push-notification, azure-mobile-services, live-tile

I'm developing a windows 8 modern UI application which requires push notification to be implemented using via windows azure notification hub.
All the sample implementation that I see requires windows 8 application to be registered with the store developer account first and then use that SID in azure service
I would like to know is there a way to implement push notification without associating the application to windows store ?

Comment: Good question. Event Live SDK can't be used w/o associating the app to windows store.

Answer (score 2):

You can't.  [The terms of use for the Windows Notification Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh694083.aspx#acr_6_9) clearly states

> 4.6 Your app must comply with Windows Push Notification Service (WNS) requirements if it uses WNS notificationsIf your app uses the Windows
>   Push Notification Service (WNS) to transmit push notifications, it
>   must do so as described in this requirement. a) You may only use WNS
>   for apps distributed through the Windows Store. Notifications provided
>   through WNS are considered app content and are subject to all Windows
>   Store app policies, including the certification requirements. b) Your
>   app must be associated with only one Package Security Identifier. c)
>   You may not obscure or try to disguise the source of any WNS message
>   or Package Security Identifier, or other unique referral identifier.
>   d) You may not include in a notification any info a customer would
>   reasonably consider to be confidential or sensitive. e) Your app must
>   not use excessive network capacity or WNS bandwidth, or otherwise
>   unduly burden the Windows system with WNS notifications. For example,
>   using WNS to stream content or transfer files violates this
>   requirement.

Which is very annoying for those of us trying to build Line-Of-Business apps that won't go through the Store.

For non-store apps you could use [Windows Azure Service Bus](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2013/05/23/announcing-the-release-of-amqp-support-with-windows-azure-service-bus.aspx) instead...but again, there is currently no support for Windows Store apps (**someone please prove me wrong**).  There is support for .NET framework 4.5, java, python, and even PHP...but not .NET Core.

Comment: Since this is an old answer, I'd like to know if someone managed to prove you wrong by chance?

Comment: @Shaamaan A Microsoft rep I met once told me that so long as you register the app with the store you can use push notifications, even if you don't actually distribute it through the store.  I haven't tested this claim, though.  I'd love to hear if it does work.

Answer (score 1):

The info in all of the samples and [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh913756.aspx#registering_wit_store) you've found is correct.  An app needs to be registered with the store to use the Windows Push Notification Service (WNS).